# In The Walking Dead, what are the "rules" of zombie "camouflage"?

Tags: the-walking-dead

I'm a little confused by this whole blending in with zombies business.  This much I do know:

- Michone and Andrea are able to camouflage themselves for an entire winter with Michones two walkers.
- Rick is able to "hide" during his fight with Shane at the prisoner drop-off site by rolling a walker on top of him.  I believe Darryl does something similar at the congested highway to save himself and T-Dawg.

The questions:

Is the camouflage literally based on a sense of smell?  Some sort of post death sixth sense?  I can't name the specific episode, but in Season one Rick and Glenn cover themselves with zombie guts to escape, and when it starts to rain, washing off some of the guts, the surrounding zombies immediately begin to take notice.  Why?  If two chained zombies can mask two adults within about a five foot radius, shouldn't that mass of zombies have been more then enough to provide cover?

By the same reasoning, as soon as the first couple zombies got close to you, shouldn't the rest of the zombies lose interest?  Is "disarming" or killing a zombie the only way to make it functional as camouflage?

Comment: Also related: [How do “pet” Walkers help ward off other Walkers?](http://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/32290/how-do-pet-walkers-help-ward-off-other-walkers)

Comment: I would say this is a different question:

As described by Eugene in the comic book, a herd is when a group of Walkers acts with a mob mentality. One zombie might brush his hand on a door knob, and another will see this and mistake it as an attempt to get in. Then he will beat on the door to get in, and the first zombie will see this and try to get in. This will spark a chain reaction. 

The closer zombies will notice the smell, and the rest of the herd will copy. If a Walker got close enough to Michone and Andrea, they would notice, and others would blindly join in too.

Comment: Also, the pets don't attack, adding to the smell with their lack of reaction, an important visual cue for other walkers. Smell matters, but a prey-reaction is important; otherwise it could just be a walker who just ate, and still has the smell on them.